# Kotlin "Unresolved reference subList"

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting "Unresolved reference: subList" when running that code
I tried to import kotlin.collections but I get the error "Packages cannot be imported"

I'm pretty new to Kotlin, I have searched online but i've got no solution, hope you can help.

I'm using Android Studio

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHaSE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you change array type and try again.

Current Type:

```
val Countries = arrayOf<String>("Angola", "Argelia")
```

Change To:

```
val Countries = mutableListOf("Angola", "Argelia")
```

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:**

Only the List interface has a subList() method.

You can use:

```
val countries = listOf("Angola", "Congo")
```

Or if you need ArrayList:

```
val countries = arrayListOf("Angola", "Congo")
```

**Second problem:**

You can not get value by index from getSerializableExtra().

If you want get extras from Intent then:

```
val indexes = intent.extras
```

If you want get Serializable object (for example: ArrayList, Bundle), then you must cast to needed class:

```
val indexes = intent.getSerializableExtra("indexes") as Bundle
```